# Swift open Maps application show specific address pins ( branches )?

Tags: swift, xcode, maps

I am trying to open Maps application on iOS from my app by providing a name of big company such as `Orange` for example and show all the company branches on the map .

so far i tried lots of solutions before i posted my question , i found this solution but its not working :

```
if let url = URL(string:"http://maps.apple.com/?address=United States,Orange S.A.") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    }
```

is it possible to find solution for my request? or i have to make my own map and pins inside the application ?

Comment: see this. https://gist.github.com/matthijsotterloo/3def603f224d83f2b8f620f2174c535e

Comment: @ugur ur code is pointing to 1 place , i need to show all pins related to specific company name , for example if u search for Microsoft it should show u all Microsoft branches

Comment: u should build query with urlEncoding like this. "United States,Orange S.A.".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)

Answer (score 0):

For People show is searching for same solution :

```
  if let url = URL(string:"http://maps.apple.com/?q=Search+Text+here") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
   }
```

- i used `q` instead of address to query the search

  also add + between words otherwise it wont work